# How to get client_id and scope of the app registered in Azure?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an app registered in Azure, and it needs to be able to communicate with dozens of different apps in my organization (those apps are also registered in Azure).
The problem is that I do not know the client_id and scope for these apps in advance.

Is it possible to retrieve this information using Graph API knowing only DNS name of the target app?

Comment: in my humble opinion, not possible

Answer (score 1):

You can call [list applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint

```
GET /applications
```

`appId` property represents `client id` that is assigned to an application by Azure AD.

`requiredResourceAccess` property has `resourceAccess` property which represents collection of `scopes`.

`resourceAccess` has `id` property which is the unique identifier of an app role or delegated permission exposed by the resource application.

Unfortunately `resourceAccess` doesn't expose any information about the name of the permission.

All Graph API permissions and their IDs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#all-permissions-and-ids)

Resources:

[resourceAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/resourceaccess?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: You or  your app will require "Application.Read.All" scope to be able to call that endpoint